# Compare two string in php and add markup

Tags: php

I want to match two string and if any words match I want to add  tag to them.

I tried something like below below code

```
$old = "one two three";

$new = "how is one related to two";

foreach (explode(" ", $old) as $str) {
    $str .= str_replace($str, "<b>$new</b>", $str);
}
echo trim($str);
```

Exptected result  `how is <b>one</b> related to <b>two</b>`.

Please suggest me some other way than looping if possible..If its not possible please tell me with looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember:

```
str_replace( look_for_this , replace_it_wtih_this, look_through_this);
```

In your code, you use `.=`, this will just copy a new sentence on every iteration. I would do it this way:

```
$old = "one two three";
$sentence = "how is one related to two";
$arr = explode(" ", $old);
foreach ($arr as $word) {
    $sentence = str_replace($word, "<b>$word</b>", $sentence);
}
echo trim($sentence);
```

Result:

```
how is <b>one</b> related to <b>two</b>
```

Comment: hey thanks ! is it possible without loop ? I have to check like 1000 sentence in single page....or only loop is the way to go ?

Comment: The amount of text to check isn't the problem, the loop would just get more iterations by you adding more words to `$old`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it, I think the mistake was using `.=` instead of `=` and also some mixed up parameters for `str_replace()` ([PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/694fb562fbe8e1741d922a585097f75ac0ed7090))

```
$searchwords = "one two three";

$string = "how is one related to two";

foreach (explode(" ", $searchwords) as $searchword) {
    $string = str_replace($searchword, "<b>{$searchword}</b>", $string);
}

echo trim($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach(explode(" ",$old) as $lol)
{
    $new = str_replace($lol, "<b>".$lol."</b>", $new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using preg_replace instead of loop

```
<?php
$pattern = "/one|two|three/i";
$string = "how is one related to two";
$replacement = "<b>$0</b>";
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo $result;
```

Result will be

```
how is <b>one</b> related to <b>two</b>
```

You can check out preg_replace from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace for all:

```
function _replace($old,$new){
    $search = str_replace(' ',')|(',$old);
    return preg_replace("/($search)/i",'<b>$0</b>',$new);
}
echo _replace("one two three","how is one related to two");
```